# Lambert W / Product log function?

Tags: logarithms

I would like to solve this equation:

$$n \cdot 2^n = 15000$$

And according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%2a%282%5En%29%20=%2015000)

$$n=\frac{W(15000\log(2))}{\log(2)}, \text{ where }\log\text{ is ln}$$

Which shows that I need to use the product log function $W$ which I tried looking up on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). I don't need the complex numbers, just real numbers.

Additionally, are there ways of solving the original equation without the $W$ functions?

Can someone explain the rules and how to do this please?

*I would eventually like to implement a way to find $n$ programmaticly (if possible-in python).*

Comment: Wolfram clearly says "$\log$" is the natural logarithm function.  So you're misquoting them.

Comment: whoops, fixed it

Comment: Surely there is some package somewhere on the 'net which implements the $W$ function.

Comment: I'm also interested in ways of solving this without the $W$ function. The initial equation doesn't look as if a solution would be difficult...but I honestly don't know.

Comment: Are you just asking how to approximate the W function numerically in general? Or just for this one particular case? If the former, then why focus on this one equation, and if the latter, then how much accuracy do you need (because W|A should be able to give a lot already). Also, the solution necessarily involves the W function - there is no other way of solving it here (except to work with the W function in disguise).

Comment: You can always implement a [root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) like bisection search or Newton's method. If you want a simple mathematical expression that directly gives $n$, it doesn't exist except in terms of the $W$ function.

Comment: @Dacto just out of curiosity: why do you want to solve it w/o W()?  I mean the solution _is_ the Lambert W function (plus a log) -- you won't find another solution. Its like saying I want to find a solution of y = exp(x) but without the logarithm -- not gonna happen ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) for finding the root of $f(n) = n 2^n - 15000 = 0$:
$$ n_{i+1} = n_i - \frac{f(n_i)}{f'(n_i)} = n_i - \frac{n_i 2^{n_i} - 15000}{2^{n_i} (1+n_i \log(2))} $$
and start with a suitable guess (look up the Wikipedia page on that). Here $n_0 = 1$ should do.You keep repeating the process for $i \ge 1$ until you reach a proper accuracy, i.e., you terminate at iteration $t$ when $n_{t} - n_{t-1} < \epsilon$ for some *tiny* $\epsilon$ you define.

Questions on exact implementation are more suitable question for [SO](http://stackoverflow.com); also [scicomp.SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) in case you're interested in details on appropriate numerical methods, and robust libraries.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222247/newtons-method-in-python

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577729-lambert-w-function/